# Is there a way to put all text on screen into an array in python3

Tags: python, discord

I am making a program that autosends a message on Discord using keyboard.py. Since it may be misused I want to make a "deathswitch".

For example: If the program is used for spam, anyone can just send a message saying >>>stop and the program ill stop.

I would like to do it by analyzing/reading all text on screen and seeing if anything matches with ">>>stop".
Here is what I have:

```
import keyboard
import os
from time import sleep
import random
import mytime
while True:
    screen = code for copying all text from the screen and putting it in a variable
    con = input("console->")
    if ">>>stop" in screen:
        print("Stopping...")
        break
    elif con == "time":
        mytime.currenttime()
    ###more elif statements
```

PS. Just to note, mytime is a program with time related things(current time, time in timezones...)

Comment: You're probably better off using the Discord API.

Comment: Instead of using keyboard.py a more robust approach might be to use this library https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ which allows you to use the discord api. this example might get you started: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot